# Getting particular data from json_encode response

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a file ajax.php which I am using to process data passed through jquery. I have this particular line of code called on successful form verification:

```
$.post("/ajax.php",{'request': 'emailLogin', 'loginmail': mail, 'loginpass': pass}, function(data) {}  );
```

data in my case is: `{"valid":true}{"auth":false}`which is returned as a response from ajax.php, but I can't seem to file the correct way of defining "auth" and a variable with value "false".

My ajax.php is just checking if login and password are in the database and than `echo json_encode(array('auth' => false));` or `echo json_encode(array('auth' => true));` depending on the result. But it has also contain these lines:

```
if( isset($_POST['loginmail'])) {
    $usermail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['loginmail']);

    if (!filter_var($usermail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $response = array('valid' => false, 'message' => 'You did not enter a correct email address.'); 
    } else {                      
        // All good
        $response = array('valid' => true);
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Your data seems to be returning two JSON objects instead of one. Once you fix that, have you set the `dataType` to `json` in `ajaxSetup`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: You should post your `ajax.php` since the problem seems to be there and not in your JS

Comment: That is correct. One is used to confirm validation, another one authentication.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov You can only return one JSON object. You need to combine them into a single array, and then call `json_encode()` on that.

Comment: Can you please include your php code that generates the response data?

Comment: I have added two lines of php that are relevant here as most of ajax.php is just checking input for its' security and searching database.

Comment: Where is `{"valid": true}` coming from?

Comment: @Barmar `{"valid": true}` is coming from the input validation.

Comment: You said you posted all the relevant PHP code. Where is that in the question?

Comment: @Barmar my apologies

Comment: I still don't see how that's ending up in the output. Are you doing `echo json_encode($response);` somewhere that you haven't shown?

Comment: @Barmar Oh yes. Sorry. Missed that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo `json_encode($response)` separately from the authentication result, you need to combine them. After you do the authentication, do:

```
$response['auth'] = $result_of_authentication;
```

then do

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Once you do this, you should be able to access `data.auth` in Javascript. You should tell `$.post` that it's returning JSON:

```
$.post("/ajax.php",{
        'request': 'emailLogin', 
        'loginmail': mail, 
        'loginpass': pass}, 
    function(data) {
        alert(data.auth);
    },
    "json");
```

Comment: I did that, good man, now my response is: `{"valid":true,"auth":"false"} `

Answer (score 0):

Based on your PHP code you should be able to access the valid attribute like so:

```
$.post("/ajax.php",{'request': 'emailLogin', 'loginmail': mail, 'loginpass': pass}, function(data) {
    var auth = data.valid;
    if (auth) {
        // do something!
    } else {
        // do something else!
    }
});
```

Also there is a bug in your PHP code, you need to set up a default value for $response like so:

```
$response = array('valid' => false, 'message' => 'Email address is required');

if( isset($_POST['loginmail'])) {
    $usermail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['loginmail']);

    if (!filter_var($usermail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $response = array('valid' => false, 'message' => 'You did not enter a correct email address.'); 
    } else {                      
        // All good
        $response = array('valid' => true);
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Otherwise if `$_POST['loginmail']` is not set your app with throw an undefined variable exception

EDIT:

As Barmar pointed out in his answer, you should only echo a response back once time to avoid creating an invalid response. Any data you need should be sent back in a single array. I don't see you doing that in your PHP code but you do make mention of echoing another array `['auth' => false]` which will not work the way you want it to

Comment: This won't work until he fixes the problem with the invalid JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure from his code where invalid JSON would be coming from. Hopefully his example data was just incorrect

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are talking about, in his question he does mention echoing json_encodeded data twice...

Comment: @JonathanCrowe I did what Barmar said and tried your jquery code, but it doesn't seem to get data out of JSON.